# Use of subprocess.Popen and subprocess.call()

Tags: python, bash, terminal, subprocess, popen

I have a problem with some functions from subprocess module, what I am trying to achieve is basically writing a python script that:

1. Opens terminal window number 1 > cd to a directory > executes a npm start command there
2. Opens terminal window number 2 > cd to different directory > executes mvn exec:exec command

I found that this will probably be achieved with the subprocess module, but I absolutely do not understand the docs ( i am not very experienced ) and dont know how to achieve this.

I will appreciate any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to:

1. `os.chdir` to your first directory
2. `subprocess.call(['cmd', 'npm', 'start'], shell=True)`
3. `os.chdir` to your second directory
4. `subprocess.call(['cmd', 'mvn', 'exec:exe'], shell=True)`

You may have to replace `cmd` with `start` or with the full path to the command shell.